# Wordpress don't show Category name in Admin panel when I try post new product

Tags: wordpress

Well, I am new to WordPress. The problem is when I try to post a new product I see the categories are missing the name as shown in the image. I use Mac and the browser is safari it got this problem. When I use Chrome on the window and iPhone safari it displays normally.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZKHA.jpg)

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO!, while asking a questions here do share code and some of the attempts you have done to solve our issue. And also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!

Comment: check posts->categories if entries are named properly

Comment: The Entires of Category is name properly